# Database design pattern for storing user data coming from external websites

Tags: mysql, sql, facebook, database-design, twitter

I'm working on an application which will allow users to register via `facebook` or `twitter` and I want to be able to use their personal data from these websites and wondering how I should store it. here is what I have come up with so far:

[image]

The `user` table would store information that should be present regardless of how the user registered, such as the `first_name`.

The `user_property` table would work as a `key-value` cache and store information that is specific to `facebook` or `twitter` (represented by the `origin` field). I would store properties that can be used as part of `API` calls or `SQL` queries individually, such as users' `facebook id` and I would store results of other `API` calls serialized in `JSON` format, such as users' `facebook friends`.

That way:

- I have common information in `user` table and with one single `SELECT` I can get some basic useful info on a user
- I have some additional properties coming from `facebook/twitter` (e.g. user id) stored individually that I can still lookup with a `JOIN` between `user` and `user_property`.
- I can retrieve information that would too expensive to store normalized (e.g. creating a table to store people's friends and have 1 table entry per friend) still with a `JOIN` between `user` and `user_property`.

And here is what I'm wondering right now:

**Q1: Could this be a somewhat sustainable database design or am I getting it wrong and going to run into some issues, and if so, which ones?**

**Q2: When storing information that is subject to frequent changes (e.g. list of friends/followers), how do you go about keeping the information up to date (do you store information in the DB in the first place? if so what criteria/triggers do you use to decide when to pull information again)?**

Comment: You should really read the terms of service for the APIs you are considering using. Most of them do not allow you to permanently store any data you retrieve through their API (only cache it for a short period of time.)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess it partly answers `Q2`, because if the terms of service say `"you're only allowed to cache for 24 hours"`, then by pulling the information every 24 hours I would comply with the terms.

Comment: Also, the backticks are really only meant for formatting code (like variable or function names). It makes it confusing when you use it for all kinds of other terms...

Answer (score 1):

Your design has most (bad) attributes of an EAV schema (Entity-Attribute-Value). Seek [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) on that matter and look around this site too.

The most non-sustainable design decision with EAV is (IMHO) that at the beginning this seems to scale well. But as soon as your data grows you hit a concrete wall with high speed. This is because in order to load the data of *one* user the DB has to touch a *huge* part of the physical table using *random access*. Tuning the DB to keep the `user_property` rows of one  user together in adjacent pages is a heavy task when the data grows and changes often.

Comment: Thanks `A.H.`: what alternative design would you suggest?

Comment: @user359650: My only advice is quite generic: Try to find structure, try to find properties which belong to each other, store these in one tuple. Also: Be clear and honest to yourself what data is really needed and how it is processed. This will sieve out most of the "oh, I *can* read data xy over there so I *will* read it and store it because I might use it *somehow* later" cruft. Instead ask: "I want to do abc *now*, what data do I need for this."

Comment: I can clearly feel the issue you're touching on here: I played with the Facebook `API` and thought: "wow, I can get some much data about my users" and the risk is definitely that I over engineer the design for data I will end up not using.